Может ли неуместное употребление неопределенно-личного местоимения "все" в предложениях и вопросах считаться преувеличением?
Замечал в Интернете вопросы, в которых используется местоимение "все", в частности на сайтах Ответы Mail.ru, Яндекс.Кью, bolshoyvopros.ru и т.п. И нередки случаи, когда отдельные пользователи на подобные вопросы отвечают либо "не все", либо "далеко не все". Может ли быть такое, что люди, которые задают подобные вопросы с местоимением "все", могут сильно преувеличивать описанную ими ситуацию, а фраза "не все"/"далеко не все" в ответ на них является индикатором того, что употребление местоимения "все" в вопросах или предложениях в подобных ситуациях неуместно?

Вопрос: Почему все популярные исполнители пишут названия песен с
маленькой буквы?


Ответ: Начнём с того, что далеко не все. Так действительно сегодня модно делать...


Преувеличивать что?

Здесь это намеренное преувеличение, имеется в виду - большая часть или же основная тенденция (мода).
